# join: reference to column is ambiguous

Tags: sql, join, db2

I want to join 2 tables with the CONT_ID parameter

```
 select (case when age_years >= 18 and age_years < 30 then '18-29'     
         when age_years < 50 then '30-49'                               
         when age_years < 70 then '50-69'                               
          when age_years < 100 then '70-100'                            
         end) as age_range,                                             
          count(DISTINCT CONT_ID) as num,                               
       SUM(ACAUT) / COUNT(*) as avg                
     from CLIENT c                                         
      left join PAYTB t                                       
       on c.CONT_ID = t.CONT_ID                                         
   group by (case when age_years >= 18 and age_years < 30 then '18-29'  
      when age_years < 50 then '30-49'                                  
      when age_years < 70 then '50-69'                                  
      when age_years < 100 then '70-100'                                
      end)                                                              
      order by min(age_years);
```

Error

SQLCODE = -203, ERROR:  A REFERENCE TO COLUMN CONT_ID IS AMBIGUOUS

Comment: Do `count(DISTINCT c.CONT_ID)` instead.

Comment: where you have `count(DISTINCT CONT_ID) as num` add the alias you've created for one of your table (`c` or `t`)...`count(DISTINCT c.CONT_ID) as num` or `count(DISTINCT t.CONT_ID) as num`

Comment: This fixed the join.

Comment: @jarlh, please post that as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify which column `CONT_ID` to use in `COUNT DISTINCT`. Instead do

```
COUNT(DISTINCT c.CONT_ID)
```